# jQuery translate text strings using an animation?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have some text, I already have the translations for it in 15 languages, I'm trying to think if this is even possible, but I'd like to essentially I have a button and when you click it, it will animate the string being translated letter by letter so we start off with Hello and you click it it goes to Bonjour and will animate that transition.

Is that even possible using jQuery animations?

Comment: transition letter by letter, or fading out old and in new at the same time? letter by letter seems like an annoyance.

Comment: No, not possible.  If you can't set the style using CSS (or if it's not a continuous property) then JQuery can't animate it.

Comment: @dbaseman maybe not using the `.animate` method, but it is possible to animate things that arent css properties. http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/xFLfj/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Just noticed your post >> *it will animate the string being translated letter by letter* <<

I am not sure how you can map which letter to what. **For ex:** Hello -> Bonjour - How will you map letter H. Also imagine how long it will take the whole page to get translated..

I would suggest to use a simple animation like `fadeOut / fadeIn` on **whole text** which is better for user too. See below,

**Markup:**

```
<div id="test">Hello</div>
<button>Translate</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$('button').click (function () {
    $('#test').fadeOut(500, function () {
       $(this).html('Bonjour').fadeIn(300);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9dq3U/1/)

**Edit:** Below code is a rough version of gradient fading. The order of animation is as below,

1. Animate opacity of the content from 1 to 0.
2. Show overlay and increase the width of the overlay from 10 to width of the content to give a shutter effect. The background of the overlay is gradient transparent so it will give gradient fading effect.
3. Update the translated message to the content and animate the opacity of the content from 0 to 1.
4. Animate the overlay width from width of the content to 0 and hide.

**The effect is still not graceful, but the code should work fine.. You may need to adjust the CSS (see instruction below) and the animation delays to get the effect that you like.**

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9dq3U/7/ (Adjust the duration to understand how it works)

```
$(function() {
    var $test = $('#test');
    var $overlay = $('.overlay');

    var tmsg = 'Bonjour<p>C\'est le message de test</p><p>Pour démontrer l\'effet de fondu</p>';

    $overlay.css({
        'width': 10,
        'height': $test.outerHeight()
    }).position({
            of: $test,
            my: 'left top',
            at: 'left top'
    });

    $('button').click(function() {

        $test.animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1000);

        $overlay.show().animate({
            'width': ($test.width() + $test.width()/2) //Adjust this as you need
        }, 600, function() {

            $overlay.css('width', $test.width()); //Adjust this as you need

            $test.html(tmsg).animate({
                'opacity': 1
            }, 200);
            $overlay.animate({
                'width': 0
            }, 1500, function() {
                $(this).hide();
            });            
        });
    });
});
```

Also below is the **CSS** for gradient transparent background for the overlay:

```
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 20%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 38%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(20%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(38%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 38%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 38%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 38%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 38%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

Of course, I didn't write the above.. It was generated with help of [Ultimate CSS gradient](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)..

1. Change the Preset (I used top right last one)
2. Change the orientation to Horizontal
3. Change the transparency level (below slider show how far you want it to be transparent)
4. Copy the CSS and paste in fiddle (I had time only to test in FF 12 and it works well)

Good Luck! Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Is there any way to use an easing function to some sort of left to right linear fadeout to give the appearance that it's fading out by letter? Edit: Besides that I think it'd work great.

Comment: The only way to achieve a directional fadeout is by animating a transparent to solid horizontal gradient over the text.

Comment: @Peter I got a trick to achieve that effect.. Let me check. **Edit:** Oh dear.. It is exactly like what Kevin suggested. Animating a div overlay over the section will give you that effect.

Comment: @Vega or Kevin B do either of you have an example of how to accomplish that? Sorry :(.

Comment: @Peter I am trying to do a sample fiddle.. Let me see if I can do it quickly.

Comment: @Peter See Updated post.. You need to spend some time to change the CSS, animation delays, width of overlay to get the effect you like.